# Specified file failed upload test. Error When Uploading Image From Front-end

Tags: uploads

This is my code:

```
$file_return = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['my-photo'], array('test_form' => FALSE));

if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])) {
    echo "And so it DIED...";
    print_r($file_return);
    die;
}
```

Why is not uploading to the uploads dir and why is it throwing a "Specified file failed upload test."?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation [wp_handle_upload](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) 
 You need to include the file.php before calling `wp_handle_upload`

`require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' )`

Comment: I am doing that and this is the error that I am getting: Specified file failed upload test.

Comment: your code is working fine. You have used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Check may be same filename already uploaded. I was getting same error because of same filename.

Comment: I can't believe and don't still understand why changing the name of the input fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_handle_upload` tries to read the file data from the lowest dimension of the given array. Like: `$file['tmp_name']`. So, if the given info is on a, i.e., secondary layer of the array (like `$file['my-photo']['image']`), it will not find the expected index, and fire a notice in your log, like this:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tmp_name

And fail the upload test. Check your error log for warnings. Also, check the method's source for your error message, this might help you a lot: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_handle_upload/#source (line #792).